# How to send Outlook email with HTML content

Tags: html-email, outlook-2010

Can anyone help me in how to send email with html content (Google Charts) using Microsoft Outlook 2010.

Below is sample html content of Google Charts.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
 <body>
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model provides the [HTMLBody](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx) property for their items. So, you can set the property to the HTML markup and then send the mail item.

You can find the sample code in the [How To: Create and send an Outlook message programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/02/outlook-create-send-message/) article.